# Excel VBA code to allow the user to choose the same cell on every sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need my user to be able to choose the same cell on every sheet 32 sheets) in the workbook, but I can't have them having to get into the code to change it. The code needs to remain protected. I have seen posts instructing to use the shift key to highlight all of the tabs, then choose the appropriate cell on one sheet and the corresponding cells are selected on all of the other sheets. The problem I have with this method is that the pertinent area of the other sheets is not necessarily visible and the user still has to scroll.

I found some code that I was able to modify to suit my needs, its easy enough to change the cell reference, but I need the user to be able to do so without getting into the code.

```
Sub GoToSelectCellOnEverySheet()

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 32
Worksheets(i).Activate

Range("A1").Select

Next i

Worksheets(1).Activate

End Sub
```

I came across something else which I thought I could modify, but this just craps out on me where I try to reference the users input. I have tried all sorts of variations of that line of code, to no avail. I don't know if I am missing something simple or if my approach is completely flawed. It dies when it gets to

```
Range.("rRange").Select
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Sub RangeDataType()

Dim rRange As Range

    On Error Resume Next

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

            Set rRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
                "Please Select A Cell", _
                    Title:="SPECIFY RANGE", Type:=8)

    On Error GoTo 0

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        If rRange Is Nothing Then

            Exit Sub

        Else

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 32

Worksheets(i).Activate

Range.("rRange").Select

Next i

Worksheets(1).Activate

        End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do something like this:

```
Set rRange = Application.InputBox(Prompt:= _
            "Please Select A Cell", _
                Title:="SPECIFY RANGE", Type:=8)

If rRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 32
    Worksheets(i).Activate
    Range(rRange.Address).Select
Next i
```

Comment: Perfect. Obviously I am on a pretty steep learning curve, but I'm glad it was something simple. Many thanks!